# For a man, is looking at uncovered non-mahram women forbidden?

Tags: men-women, non-mahram

I know that looking at an uncovered non-mahram women is forbidden, but I saw some Islamic YouTubers namely Ali Dawah and Sheikh Omar Suleiman looking at uncovered women as like it is not forbidden.

So I'm confused now, as I consider them as sincere people.

Also they didn't do this meaninglessly, they were engaged in Dawah to those women.

So could you throw some light here with references from the Qur'an and Sunnah?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll [assume](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/954/dont-assume-other-users-are-male) this question is about men looking at uncovered women; rulings for women looking at uncovered women are different.

Basically it boils down to the ayah:

> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 24:30](https://quran.com/24/30)</sub>

(Which is reinforced by ahadith such as [Sahih al-Bukhari 5066](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/4): *Whoever among you can marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze and guard his modesty*.)

It's one of the steps men can take to guard their chastity.  [AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/32147) describes this verse as *a command of Allāh Ta‘āla for men to lower their gazes from non-Mahram women*.  It's normally considered obligatory for a man to lower their gaze in front of non-mahram women:

> If your eyes fell on a non-Mahram woman, you have to avert your eyes from her.  It is impermissible for you to look at the faces of non-Mahram women intentionally, even if it is without lust.
>   <sub>[IslamWeb](http://islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=352714)</sub>

There's exceptions regarding e.g., the first glance at a woman, and for old women ([AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/29208)), and when considering a woman for marriage ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=81668)).  There's also some slight differences of opinion:

> It is Haraam for one to gaze at a non-Mahram woman with desire and Makrooh Tahreemi (severely disliked) to do so if there is no desire.
>   <sub>[AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/29208)</sub>

Different Muslim men implement this in various ways and with various level of success.

Comment: But Rebecca in School, I have uncovered non - mahram female teachers and also female classmates without any hijab. In this scenario , with mental strength one might refrain himself from looking at fellow classmates of the opposite gender but it is impossible for one to not look at the teacher while she is teaching. Then if one insists on not looking at the teacher he will lag behind severely in education and it also might create an embarrassing and awkward situation one day. So what should I do now?

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan Can you put this comment as a separate question? It is not advisable to ask multiple queries in a single question. Thank You.

Comment: @Ahmed Thanks for giving me this important advise, Zazakallahu khairan!!

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan Wa iyakkum bi khair ya akhi.